# Join 3 tables and get record based on latest value only

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table as follow:

Schema (MySQL v5.7)

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    Stud_ID varchar(255),
    Stud_Name varchar(255),
    Program varchar(255),
    Disablity_Code int
);

CREATE TABLE Disability  
(
    Disability_Code int,
    Disability_Desc varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentSemHistory 
(
    Stud_ID varchar(255),
    Stud_Status varchar(255),
    Semester int,
    Stud_Session varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Student (Stud_ID, Stud_Name, Program, Disablity_Code)
VALUES
('K001', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'AA101', '1'),
('K002', 'Maria Debuchy', 'AA101', '2'),
('K003', 'Alex Olson', 'AA101', '2'),
('K004', 'Bob Rocker', 'AA101', '3'),
('K005', 'Susan Lancaster', 'AA101', '1');

INSERT INTO Disability (Disability_Code, Disability_Desc)
VALUES 
('1', 'Normal'),
('2', 'Vision Impairment'),
('3', 'Intellectual Disability');

INSERT INTO StudentSemHistory (Stud_ID, Stud_Status, Semester, Stud_Session)
VALUES 
('K001', 'Inactive', '1', '0720'),
('K001', 'Inactive', '2', '0121'),
('K001', 'Inactive', '3', '0421'),
('K002', 'Inactive', '1', '0720'),
('K002', 'Inactive', '2', '0121'),
('K002', 'Inactive', '3', '0421'),
('K002', 'Active', '4', '0721'),
('K003', 'Inactive', '1', '0720'),
('K003', 'Inactive', '2', '0121'),
('K003', 'Inactive', '3', '0421'),
('K003', 'Active', '4', '0721'),
('K004', 'Inactive', '1', '0720'),
('K004', 'Inactive', '2', '0121'),
('K005', 'Inactive', '1', '0720'),
('K005', 'Inactive', '2', '0121'),
('K005', 'Inactive', '3', '0421'),
('K005', 'Active', '4', '0721');
```

Query #1:

```
select S.Stud_ID, S.Stud_Name, S.Program, hist.Semester, hist.Stud_Status, D.Disability_Desc
from Student S 
inner join Disability D on S.Disablity_Code = D.Disability_Code
left join (select distinct Stud_ID, Semester, Stud_Status from StudentSemHistory
           group by Stud_ID, Semester, Stud_Status) as hist
            on hist.Stud_ID = S.Stud_ID

where S.Disablity_Code <> 1;
```

| Stud_ID | Stud_Name | Program | Semester | Stud_Status | Disability_Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K002 | Maria Debuchy | AA101 | 1 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K002 | Maria Debuchy | AA101 | 2 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K002 | Maria Debuchy | AA101 | 3 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K002 | Maria Debuchy | AA101 | 4 | Active | Vision Impairment |
| K003 | Alex Olson | AA101 | 1 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K003 | Alex Olson | AA101 | 2 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K003 | Alex Olson | AA101 | 3 | Inactive | Vision Impairment |
| K003 | Alex Olson | AA101 | 4 | Active | Vision Impairment |
| K004 | Bob Rocker | AA101 | 1 | Inactive | Intellectual Disability |
| K004 | Bob Rocker | AA101 | 2 | Inactive | Intellectual Disability |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

The question is, how to make the output display the latest semester only which mean it will display 1 student per row with their latest semester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be to join using max of Semester -

```
select S.Stud_ID, S.Stud_Name, S.Program, hist.Semester,D.Disability_Desc
, sem.Stud_Status
from Student S inner join Disability D on S.Disablity_Code = D.Disability_Code
left join (select distinct Stud_ID, max(Semester) as Semester from StudentSemHistory
           group by Stud_ID) as hist
            on hist.Stud_ID = S.Stud_ID
join StudentSemHistory sem on sem.Stud_ID = hist.Stud_ID
and sem.Semester = hist.Semester
where S.Disablity_Code <> 1
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7AsjUvMvtS2QZkdqAnoiA/0)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is inside your left join. You shouldn't put semester on `group by` parameter.
You have to order it by Semester first then group it by `Stud_ID`.

```
select S.Stud_ID, S.Stud_Name, S.Program, hist.Semester, hist.Stud_Status, D.Disability_Desc
from Student S
inner join Disability D on S.Disablity_Code = D.Disability_Code
left join (select distinct Stud_ID, Semester, Stud_Status from StudentSemHistory
           group by Stud_ID, Stud_Status order by Semester Desc) as hist
            on hist.Stud_ID = S.Stud_ID

where S.Disablity_Code <> 1;
```

or

```
select S.Stud_ID, S.Stud_Name, S.Program, hist.Semester, hist.Stud_Status, D.Disability_Desc
from Student S
inner join Disability D on S.Disablity_Code = D.Disability_Code
left join (select distinct Stud_ID, Semester, Stud_Status from StudentSemHistory
           group by Stud_ID, Stud_Status order by Semester Desc) as hist
            on hist.Stud_ID = S.Stud_ID

where S.Disablity_Code <> 1 GROUP BY S.Stud_ID;
```